# Setting CORS config for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, ddos

To optimize my server usage I moved the images (~500) and rendered `HTML` files for `SEO` (~1000) to `S3` storage & it works just fine, however, I am worried about having a `DDoS` attack which will, in the end, cost me a lot of money, since Amazon charges for every `GET` request.

I did some research on how to prevent that and found out that there is a `CORS` config option for `S3`.

I tried it out, but unfortunately, it didn't seem to work. Can still access the files from any `URL`

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Also tried to set bucket policy:

[image]

Comment: And if I don't set public access, I can't load it even from the origin website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CORS configuration permits **cross-domain requests**. It is not a method for restricting access to files.

By default, **browsers will not allow cross-domain requests**. For example, the browser will not allow a page served from `example1.com` to access content from `example2.com`. This is done to protect your personal information, such as people trying to open iframes to Facebook to access your personal Facebook content.

If, however, `example2.com` is willing to permit this cross-domain request, then it can add a Cross Original Resource Sharing (CORS) policy that says that `example1.com` is permitted to access the content in a cross-domain manner. The **web browser** will then permit the access.

**In summary:** It is your web browser that is controlling CORS. The CORS policy just tells the web browser to permit it.

See: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

**Restricting by Referrer**

Your particular requirement, however, appears to be that you are willing to serve content from Amazon S3, but only if it appears on a particular web page. For example, only show images from `images.example.com` if it is being requested by a page served by `example.com`. You can achieve this by **specifying a Referrer in an Amazon S3 Bucket Policy**.

From [Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It is relatively easy to fake a referrer, but this should generally give you what you are seeking.

Comment: well, I did what you suggested, but it still doesn't restrict it. Check the update to the question

Comment: Try this: Remove the bucket policy and check whether the objects are accessible. If they are still accessible, then something else is granting access (eg permissions on the objects themselves, an IAM User policy) and you have to remove that to make them private again. Then, add the above policy and it should work fine.